# C++/CLI: How to write property of the property

Tags: c#, properties, c++-cli

I have 2 ref classes in C++/CLI:

***>The first class:***

```
 public ref class wBlobFilter
    {
        int  mMin;
        int  mMax;
        bool mIsActive;

    public:

        //  min value
        property int Min
        {
            int get() {return mMin;}
            void set(int value) {mMin = value;}
        }

        //  max value
        property int Max
        {
            int get(){return mMax;}
            void set(int value){mMax = value;}
        }

        //  set to true to active
        property bool IsActive
        {
            bool get() {return mIsActive;}
            void set(bool value){mIsActive = value;}
        }
    };
```

***>The second class:***

```
    public ref class wBlobParams
    {
        wBlobFilter mFilter;

    public:

        property wBlobFilter Filter
        {
            wBlobFilter get() {return mFilter;}
            void set(wBlobFilter value) { mFilter = value; }
        }
    };
```

when I call it in C# I got an error message : **"Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable"**

```
        Params.Filter.Min = 0;
```

So, how can I set the value of the member variable of class wBlobFilter through class wBlobParams's property directly ? Sorry for my bad English. Thank you!!!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `wBlobFilter^` instead of `wBlobFilter` in cli code?

Comment: If it inherits then the properties from the filter will be available.

public ref class wBlobParams : public wBlobFilter
{ ... };   I can't tell if that's what you are after.

Comment: I've tried  but its not my problem.
 
I don't want to inherit wBlobParams from wBlobFilter, wBlobFilter is only a member of wBlobParams but I want to set value for it through wBlobParams's property. Like this: 

`Params.Filter.Min = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what exactly you want to happen. If it inherits then the properties from the filter will be available.

```
public ref class wBlobParams : public wBlobFilter
{};

void f(wBlobParams^ params) {
    auto max = params->Max;
}
```

Or replicate the property access in wBlobParams:

```
public ref class wBlobParams {
public:
    wBlobFilter^ mFilter;

    property int Max {
        int get() { return mFilter->Max; }
    }
};

void f(wBlobParams^ params) {
    auto max = params->Max;
}
```

Edit 1:
Look at this. What you were doing was fine. Just your syntax for using gc handles is wrong.

```
public ref class cA {
    int x;

public:
    cA() : x(0) {}

    property int X  {
        int get() { return x; }
        void set(int _x) { x = _x; }
    }
};

public ref class cB {
    cA^ a;
public:
    cB() : a(gcnew cA()) {}

    property cA^ A  {
        cA^ get() { return a; }
        void set(cA^ _a) { a = _a; }
    }
};

void main() {
    cB^ b = gcnew cB();
    b->A->X = 5;
    Console::WriteLine(b->A->X);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to inherit wBlobParams  from wBlobFilter, wBlobFilter is only a member of wBlobParams but I want to set value for it  through wBlobParams's property. Like this:

`Params.Filter.Min = 0;`

Comment: @tuka: Thank you so much.I understood. 
is it wrong If I change class cA from ref to value ??

Comment: @DungTv the "ref class" keyword means the object must be used by reference. I don't know any way around that but I'm also new to all this. There is a syntax exception for local variables seeming like they are on the stack even though they aren't. I don't think anything like that is possible for member variables.